# WSGI Python Flask apache2 на ubuntu возвращает ошибку

Tags: python, apache, flask, wsgi, mod-wsgi

У меня есть VPS сервер, на котором нужно запустить API для обработки регистраций.
При запуске apache сервера (по этой инструкции - https://www.8host.com/blog/razvyortyvanie-prilozheniya-flask-na-servere-ubuntu/) вылезает ошибка SyntaxError: invalid syntax.

```
[Wed Aug 16 13:35:07.173522 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 63783:tid 139809708308224]  Traceback (most recent call last):
[Wed Aug 16 13:35:07.173537 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 63783:tid 139809708308224]    File "/var/www/API/API.wsgi", line 6, in <module>
[Wed Aug 16 13:35:07.173575 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 63783:tid 139809708308224]      from API import app as application
[Wed Aug 16 13:35:07.173602 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 63783:tid 139809708308224]    File "/var/www/API/API/__init__.py", line 54
[Wed Aug 16 13:35:07.173606 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 63783:tid 139809708308224]      async def start(message: types.Message):
[Wed Aug 16 13:35:07.173609 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 63783:tid 139809708308224]          ^
[Wed Aug 16 13:35:07.173612 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 63783:tid 139809708308224]  SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Хотя при запуске "в лоб" через SSH соединение в консоли Ubuntu всё работет, ошибок не выдаёт.

Вот сам код, некоторые функции закоментированны или пока не выполняют то, что я хочу, но это не первостепенно.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import asyncio
import contextvars
import functools
import random
import sqlite3
from datetime import datetime
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request
from flask_cors import CORS

from aiogram import Bot, types
from aiogram.dispatcher import Dispatcher
from aiogram.utils import executor
import functions as func

# try:
#     conn = sqlite3.connect("db/database.db")
#     cursor = conn.cursor()
#
# except sqlite3.Error as error:
#     print("Возникла ошибка в Д - ", error)

bot = Bot(token="MY-TOKEN")
dp = Dispatcher(bot)

# @dp.message_handler(commands=["start"])
# async def start(message: types.Message):
#
#     try:
#         args = str(message.get_args())
#
#         local_database_id = cursor.execute("SELECT id FROM users WHERE local_id = (?)", (args,)).fetchone()
#
#         if local_database_id:
#             await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Регистрация завершена, ваш ID - " + args)
#     except:
#         await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Привет. Это бот от Sample Code. \nВот наш сайт: https://")

import re
import sqlite3
import random
# from telebot import TeleBot, types

try:
    conn = sqlite3.connect("db/database.db")
    cursor = conn.cursor()
except sqlite3.Error as error:
    print("Возникла ошибка в БД - ", error)
# bot = TeleBot(token="мой-токен")


@dp.message_handler(commands=["start"])
async def start(message: types.Message):
    try:
        args = extract_start_argument(message.text)
        local_database_id = cursor.execute("SELECT id, password, phone_verification, phone FROM users WHERE local_id = ?", (args,)).fetchone()
        print(1)
        if local_database_id:
            user_id, password, phone_verification, phone = local_database_id
            print(2)
            if not password:
                password = generate_password()
                cursor.execute("UPDATE users SET password = ? WHERE id = ?", (password, user_id))
                cursor.execute("UPDATE users SET telegram_id = ? WHERE id = ?", (message.from_user.id, user_id))
                conn.commit()
                print(3)

            if not phone_verification:
                await bot.send_message(user_id,
                                 f"Привет! Пожалуйста, подтверди свой номер телефона.", reply_markup=create_phone_verification_keyboard())
            else:
                await bot.send_message(user_id, "Регистрация уже завершена.")
        else:
            await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Неверный local_id.")
    except:
        await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Привет. Это бот от Sample Code. \nВот наш сайт: https://")


@dp.message_handler(content_types=["contact"])
async def handle_contact(message: types.Message):
    try:
        user_id = message.from_user.id
        local_database_id = cursor.execute("SELECT id, phone, phone_verification FROM users WHERE telegram_id = ?",
                                           (user_id,)).fetchone()

        if local_database_id:
            _, db_phone, phone_verification = local_database_id
            provided_phone = message.contact.phone_number

            if db_phone == provided_phone:
                if not phone_verification:
                    cursor.execute("UPDATE users SET phone_verification = ? WHERE id = ?", ("verified", _))
                    conn.commit()
                    password = cursor.execute("SELECT password FORM users WHERE id = ?", (_,)).fetchone()
                    formatted_password = f"`{password}`"
                    await bot.send_message(user_id, f"Номер телефона успешно подтверждён. Твой пароль - {formatted_password}", parse_mode="MarkdownV2")
                else:
                    await bot.send_message(user_id, "Номер телефона уже был подтверждён ранее.")
            else:
                cursor.execute("UPDATE users SET phone = ? WHERE id = ?", (provided_phone, user_id))
                conn.commit()
                await bot.send_message(user_id, "Номер телефона обновлён. Пожалуйста, подтвердите его.")
        else:
            await bot.send_message(user_id, "Ошибка: пользователь не найден.")
    except:
        await bot.send_message(user_id, "Произошла ошибка при обработке контакта.")


def generate_password(length=12):
    characters = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789!@#$%^&*()_+-=[]{}|;:,.<>?~"
    password = "".join(random.choice(characters) for _ in range(length))
    return password


def create_phone_verification_keyboard():
    keyboard = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(one_time_keyboard=True, resize_keyboard=True)
    button = types.KeyboardButton("Подтвердить номер телефона", request_contact=True)
    keyboard.add(button)
    return keyboard

def extract_start_argument(text):
    match = re.search(r"/start\s+(\S+)", text)
    if match:
        return match.group(1)
    return None

# if __name__ == "__main__":
#     bot.polling()

async def to_thread(func, /, *args, **kwargs):
    loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
    ctx = contextvars.copy_context()
    func_call = functools.partial(ctx.run(), func, *args, **kwargs)
    return await loop.run_in_executor(None, func_call)

# app = Flask(__name__, subdomain_matching=True)
# app.config['SERVER_NAME'] = "api.сайт.ru:5555"
# app.config['SERVER_NAME'] = "api.сайт.ru"
app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app)

@app.route("/api")
async def api():
    return "<h1><br>To get access to the API, please contact us - почта@gmail.com</br></h1>"

@app.route("/api/register", methods=['GET'])
async def register():
    try:
        conn = sqlite3.connect("db/database.db")
        cursor = conn.cursor()

    except sqlite3.Error as error:
        print("Возникла ошибка в БД - ", error)

    def phone_unically(phone):
        phone_db = cursor.execute("SELECT phone FROM users WHERE phone = (?)", (phone,)).fetchone()
        if phone_db:
            return False
        else:
            return True

    def email_unically(email):
        email_db = cursor.execute("SELECT email FROM users WHERE email = (?)", (email,)).fetchone()
        if email_db:
            return False
        else:
            return True






    try:
        full_name = request.args.get('full_name')
    except:
        return jsonify({"error": "ФИО не указано", "status":"bad"})

    try:
        birth_date = request.args.get('birth_date')

        current_date = datetime.now()

        # Преобразуем строку с датой рождения в объект datetime
        birth_date_1 = datetime.strptime(birth_date, "%Y-%m-%d")

        # Вычисляем разницу между текущей датой и датой рождения
        age = current_date.year - birth_date_1.year

        # Проверяем, достиг ли возраст 18 лет или более
        if current_date.month < birth_date_1.month or (
                current_date.month == birth_date_1.month and current_date.day < birth_date_1.day):
            age -= 1

        if age >= 14:
            pass
        else:
            return jsonify({"error": "Вам меньше 14 лет", "status":"bad"})

    except:
        return jsonify({"error": "Дата рождения не указана", "status":"bad"})

    try:
        email = request.args.get('email')
        if email_unically(email):

            pass
        else:
            return jsonify({"error": "Указанный EMAIL уже был использован для регистрации",  "status":"bad"})


    except:
        return jsonify({"error": "EMAIL не указан", "status":"bad"})

    try:
        phone = request.args.get('phone').replace(" ", "")

        if phone_unically(phone):
            pass
        else:
            return jsonify({"error": "Указанный номер телефона уже был использован для регистрации", "status":"bad"})

    except:
        return jsonify({"error": "Номер телефона не указан", "status":"bad"})


    local_id = str(random.randint(0, 999999))
    print(local_id)
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO users (full_name, birth_date, email, phone, local_id) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)", (full_name, birth_date, email, phone, local_id,))
    conn.commit()

    # user_id = await func.get_chat_id(phone)
    # print(user_id)
    # await bot.send_message(user_id, "ТЕСТ")
    await bot.send_message(1060614786, f"<b>Новая регистрация на курс! \n\nДанные:</b> \nФИО: {full_name}\nТелефон: {phone}\nEmail: {email}\nLocal id: {local_id}", parse_mode="HTML")

    return jsonify({"error": "", "status":"ok", "local_id": local_id})

@app.route("/api/no_tg", methods=["GET"])
async def no_tg():
    try:
        local_id = request.args.get('local_id')
    except:
        return jsonify({"error": "ФИО не указано", "status":"bad"})
    await bot.send_message(1060614786, f"Пользователь *{local_id}* не может подтвердить регистрацию в телеграмме, отпрвьте инструкцию на почту")
    return jsonify({"status":"ok"})

async def start(host, port):
    # asyncio.create_task(await to_thread(app.run(host=host, port=port)))
    asyncio.create_task(await to_thread(app.run()))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    async def start_func():
        asyncio.create_task(await to_thread(executor.start_polling(dispatcher=dp, skip_updates=False, on_startup=await start(host="0.0.0.0", port="5555"))))

    asyncio.run(start_func())
```

Comment: Во-первых, я не уверен, что такое смешивание aiogram и Flask вообще будет нормально работать. Во-вторых, если вы пытаетесь запускать Python-код через libapache2-mod-wsgi, то начать стоит с логичного вопроса — а какая версия Python используется в libapache2-mod-wsgi и поддерживает ли эта версия асинхронщину вообще?

Comment: С aiogram согласен - не лучшее решение, пока просто тестирую, может потом какую нибудь CRM прикручу или использую библиотеку без асинхронности. Но спасибо за подсказку, попробую убрать асинхронность или использовать libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3